# Update all columns in ormlite database table in Android

Tags: android, orm

I have the following database table object:

```
public class Goal {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String goal_title;
    @DatabaseField
    private String goal_desc;
    @DatabaseField
    private String goal_why;
    ...
}
```

I have added some rows to this table and now I want to write a query to update all the columns of a row in this table.  I have seen documentation of ORM and could not get an idea how to write this query. Please help me how to write this query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I have added some rows to this table and now I want to write a query to update all the columns of a row in this table.

I think you need to RTFM.  I've spent a long time on the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) documentation and I think it [covers the `UpdateBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/docs/update-builder) pretty well.  Feel free to ask more specific questions and I can add more details if not.

To quote from the docs:

> The DAO can also be used to construct custom UPDATE and DELETE statements. Update statements are used to change certain fields in rows from the table that match the WHERE pattern - or update all rows if no where(). Delete statements are used to delete rows from the table that match the WHERE pattern - or delete all rows if no where().

To tweak the example code to use your `Goal` object:

```
UpdateBuilder<Goal, Integer> updateBuilder = goalDao.updateBuilder();
// update the goal_title and goal_why fields
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("goal_title", "some other title");
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("goal_why", "some other why");
// but only update the rows where the description is some value
updateBuilder.where().eq("goal_desc", "unknown description");
// actually perform the update
updateBuilder.update();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Gray for your response and I just tried this code but it is giving an error on last line 

updateBuilder.update() , that update method does not exist for type updateBuilder. There are two other methods updateColumnExpression and updateColumnValue, but not the update method . Please help if u get my problem. Thanks again

Comment: That was added in version 4.34.  It is short hand for `goalDao.update(updateBuilder.prepare());`

Comment: goalDao.update(updateBuilder.prepare()); also not working  :( , and again giving an error that this is undefined for type updateBuilder. I have ormlite 4.30, should i use 4.34 ?

Comment: Wow.  So use `goalDao.update(updateBuilder.prepareStatement());`.  We are on 4.41 now: http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt

Comment: Could you plz give me the link from where i can download 4.41 of orm ?

Comment: RTFM is totally true. But, only good when the docs site is up and not showing "This webpage is not available" for a whole day.

Comment: I am using "ormlite-android-4.43.jar" & "ormlite-core-4.43.jar". 
how to update table completely without UpdateBuilder.
.update(course); not working for me ?

Comment: .update(course); not working for me ?
.delete(course); not working.. 
.create(course); is working fine...

Comment: Maybe send mail to the mailing list?  Check the full exception for details especially the caused-by messages @vishnupriyan.

Comment: @Gray:How to update whole bean using where condition ? please give suggestion for it.